# Is there an idiom to say "However hard we try/ teach, nothing goes in"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

> He seems to learn nothing. However hard we teach, nothing goes in.

Is there a word equivalent, an idiom or expression to say "however hard we try/teach, nothing goes in"?

Comment: Unless the person you want to label as "unteachable" suffers from [Anterograde Amnesia](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/23221-anterograde-amnesia) / [Goldfield’s syndrome](https://www.behavenet.com/goldfields-syndrome), it's unlikely he is unable to absorb and retain *any* new information. So it probably makes a difference ***what you're trying to teach him*** (with perhaps some indication of ***why*** he doesn't want to learn whatever it is). For all I know, perhaps he just thinks his teachers are full of sh*t.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this covers your situation completely, but it's often said of someone who resists instruction that they're an ***[airhead](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/airhead)*** (M/W) or that your words *go in one ear and out the other*

Comment: Airhead- seems bit rude ...

Comment: Suggesting that someone is immune to learning is a bit rude in the first place.

Comment: *It goes in one ear and out the other* is a bit less rude than *airhead*, although it's not usually complimentary.

Answer (score 2):

“You can lead a horse to water but you can’t make it drink” this means you can try to teach something but it is up to them to learn it. Often times said when the subject is refusing to “drink the water”

Comment: Nice... but a friend of mine squared up the problem  by citing  an expression  even if you "SPOON FEED" him, he TAKES nothing IN.it sounds  satisfying to me.

Comment: @Selfiegroupie Yes, but what your friend said is **not an idiom** whereas this answer has one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expression ***[slow on the uptake](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/be-quick-slow-on-the-uptake):***

> If someone is quick/slow on the uptake, they understand things easily/with difficulty:
>
> - He's a little slow on the uptake, so you may have to repeat the instructions a few times.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You could just describe such a person as **unteachable,** [defined by MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unteachable) as "unable to be taught."

Comment: Yes, unteachable... but not so attractive to me. I would like to have  an equivalent expression to say "HOWEVER HARD I TEACH HIM"

Comment: You need to explain the exact context in which this will be used for us to find a suitable replacement.

Comment: Say this guy understands Science .So we teach him this  WITH EASE. But, he struggles to understand English, being a non native speaker. So, nothing works even if we try  our level best....

Comment: Please put this into your question (and fix the punctuation).

Answer (score 0):

This idiom from *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English* fits the bill:

**be none the wiser/not be any the wiser**

> to not understand something even after it has been explained to you

*Charlie explained how the system works, but I’m still none the wiser.*

Answer (score 0):

**It's like I'm talking to a brick wall.**

Oddly, Urban Dictionary appears to have the best definition of how this expression is most commonly used.

> Talking to a brick wall is a phrase used to sarcastically explain that
> the person you are talking to is not listening or is so dumb that
> they don't understand.
> Wow you're so stupid it's like talking to a
> brick wall
> by Ohdearlol December 28, 2013

Also often in the form of "I may as well have been talking to a brick wall". For example "I did tell them to wash the equipment before they put it away, but I may as well have been talking to a brick wall".